# What to do if "mousemove" and "click" events fire simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I don't know whether it is only *Chrome* problem (can't check now), however let's try the following piece of code, where we bind two events to some element:

```
$("div").on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        console.log("move");
    },
    click: function(e) {
        console.log("click");
    }
});
```

If we try to click the element, we'll find that for some reason `mousemove` event fires immediately after click, so in console we have:

```
>> ...
>> click
>> move
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/

Note, that `mousedown` and `mouseup` events work by the same scenario.

I saw many questions on SO about the same problem, but none (in my search) gave the straightforward idea what to do in order to fire the `click` event *only*.

Comment: Mice move all the time.  The problem is your program depending on not moving the mouse when clicking.

Comment: Seems the mousemove event fires on click as well, did'nt know that, and tried logging the event, and can't find anything different then a regular mousemove to seperate them either. Hard nut to crack this one? Here's one way to work around it [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/2/) ...

Comment: Why is this a problem? The user can legitimately move the mouse and click so that a "real" move follows a click as far as your code is concerned. It should be able to handle this without issues.

Comment: On Chrome 25 (OSX) 'click' fires on click and 'move' fires on move. No problem whatsoever.

Comment: When using a touchpad (laptop) `mousemove` is not triggered (Chrome 24, OSX). So either you really move the mouse while clicking or input devices are treated differently or it is fixed in that version. Firefox does not trigger `mousemove` either.

Comment: I see this issue on Chrome 23, but not on Firefox 18 or IE8.  This is using a Lenovo touchpad.  (Update: I just upgraded Chrome to 24 on Win7 and still see the issue)

Comment: @Jon In my current experiments I log all events to array in order to work with them later. The basic idea is to do logging in the most compact way, and extra events just add extra weight.

Comment: FF 17 on OSX also works as @Oleg described.

Comment: @Felix Looks like it is treated differently on different devices, since I definitely do not move the mouse when do the click, I'm fine `:D`

Comment: In the jQuery doc they say
_However, high frequency events such as mousemove or scroll can fire dozens of times per second, and in those cases it becomes more important to use events judiciously. Performance can be increased by reducing the amount of work done in the handler itself, caching information needed by the handler rather than recalculating it, or by rate-limiting the number of actual page updates using setTimeout._

I was trying to play around with setTimeout but couldn't get anything :/ maybe someone else can? I guess this isn't really a performance issue though...

Comment: I see this on Chrome 24, but not Firefox 18, IE 9 or Opera 11.

Comment: I see this in Chrome 24 as well. @aug - how does that explain it ?

Comment: There was a chromium bug report opened for this back in November: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464

Comment: @adeneo I guess doesn't really explain but I was thinking their suggestion could have been useful maybe somehow delaying the mousemove so there's time to see if a click has been registered (even if it is a millisecond or so).

Comment: For me, without moving the mouse (even not touching it), mousemove is fired hundreds time on chrome 24 windows 7. Seems like a tick fired it. Thats really a weird bug.

Comment: There is a great deal of difference between Console panel in chrome and console in firebug. I have always had conflicting resulting in chrome console as compared with Firebug Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is odd, and it doesn't seem to occur universally (happens in Chrome/IE for me, but not FFX).  I think you haven't gotten a straight answer because there isn't one really.

It's possible that the mouse is moved very slightly by the click action, but that's probably not it.  Could just be a browser quirk.  These don't even seem to be the same event since `stopImmediatePropagation` in `click` doesn't stop `mousemove` from firing.  If you focus the element and hit a keyboard button, it will actually trigger `click` and *only* `click`.

Since this is so quirky, it seems like the only way to deal with it is times.  As much of a kludge as this is, I do notice that `click` happens one millisecond *before* `mousemove`, so you could get close by comparing the click timestamp + 2 (or 10):

```
mousemove: function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('lastClick') + 10 < e.timeStamp) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/3/

This is very specific, though.  You should consider not having behavior that occurs immediately on mousemove since it's so frequent.

Comment: +1 That's a good suggestion. In order to make `mousemove` event *work* from the start, you need to add the check for undefined data, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/4/.

Comment: @VisioN I didn't have a problem with that, but I agree that yours is more technically correct

Comment: The problem is that `undefined + 10 === NaN`, while `NaN < e.timeStamp` gives `false`, hence while there is no default value set, the `movemove` event won't be triggered.

Comment: @VisioN - posted a fiddle 20 minutes ago that does this (almost) ??

Comment: @adeneo Didn't see your fiddle. That's a good alternative, you should post is as answer.

Comment: My problem with this is that I need to set the threshold (10 in your case) so high that I start disregarding actual mousemove events in an attempt to avoid all the fraudulent ones. I've had to set it as high as 35-50 ms

Comment: in FF I find mousemove events fire when even just clicking

Comment: I can confirm that in Chrome 69 on Windows 10, mousemove fires on the body and the document before a button's click handler fires. See https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/mzOBpX

Answer (score 9):

Mousemove appears to be binded to every mouse action there is in Chrome, so store the mouse position every time the mouse "moves" and check it against the previous mouse position to validate that it has indeed "moved"..

```
var currentPos=[];
$("div").on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        if (e.pageX!==currentPos[0] && e.pageY !==currentPos[1]){
            currentPos=[e.pageX,e.pageY];
        this.innerHTML = "Event: " + e.type;
        console.log("move");
        }
    },
    click: function(e) {
        this.innerHTML = "Event: " + e.type;
        console.log("click");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/8/show) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/8/)

Comment: I guess you shouldn't mix `window.event` with `e` object. Otherwise, your solution also makes sense.

Comment: The timeStamp hack didn't work for me but this one did.

Comment: This is a good solution, but won't work if a click event is adding a mouse move event listener to start a drag listening sequence.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome that was first reported back in November, and remains open.

[Chromium Issue 161464](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464)

If you are targeting Chrome specifically then it may be worth comparing the event timestamps to get around it (using some minimum delta time as @ExplosionPills suggested.  But if you're looking for general behavior it seems that you're better off treating them as separate events, because in every browser but chrome (and maybe Safari? the bug is labeled as webkit-core) they will in fact be separate events.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't just check that did the mouse really move or not like below:

```
function onMouseDown (e) {
    mouseDown = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
    console.log("click");
}

function onMouseMove (e) {
    //To check that did mouse really move or not
    if ( e.clientX !== mouseDown.x || e.clientY !== mouseDown.y) {
        console.log("move");
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gKqVt/91/)

(I think it's will still correct in all browsers)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a,b,c,d;
  $(".prd img").on({
 mousedown: function(e){
   a= e.clientX, b= e.clientY;
 },
 mouseup: function(e){
   c= e.clientX, d= e.clientY;
   if(a==c&&b==d){
     console.log('clicked');
   }
 }
  });
```

Try this. This one work correct.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this behavior when I needed to differenciate between mousedown and mouseup without dragging between the two and mousedown and mouseup with dragging between them, the solution that I used is as follows:

```
var div = $('#clickablediv');
var mouseDown = false;
var isDragging = 0;
div.mousedown(function () {
   isDragging = false;
       mouseDown = true;
   }).mousemove(function () {
       if (mouseDown) isDragging++;
   }).mouseup(function () {
       mouseDown = false;
       var wasDragging = isDragging;
       isDragging = 0;
       if (!wasDragging || wasDragging<=1) {
           console.log('there was no dragging');
       }
   });
```

when I tried it, I noticed that periodacaly a simple click makes "isDragging" equal to 3 but not very frequently

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my mouseMove(event) function:

```
      function mouseMove(event)
      {
        if ((event.movementX == 0) && (event.movementY == 0)) return;
```

Not clear why it triggers when there is no movement, but this worked for me. Had the issue in Chrome 102.0.5005.61 at least. It did not happen a few years ago.