# Mouse event "mousemove" gets fired when pressing and releasing mouse buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, mousemove, mouseup

As title says, I noticed that on my canvas `mousemove` is fired when mouse buttons are pressed/released even though I'm not actually moving the mouse. The problem is that, in the case of releasing the button, it gets fired AFTER `mouseup`!

**Is that normal behaviour?**
How to fix/workaround? I really need my `mouseup` to fire last, or `mousemove` not to fire at all when releasing buttons; `setTimeout` is not a legit solution.

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/h40mm4mj/1/ As simple as that: if you open console and click in the canvas, you'll notice `mousemove` is logged after `mouseup`

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  console.log("mousemove");
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  console.log("mouseup");
}, false);
```

EDIT: Just tested, it only happens on Chromium, Windows.

Comment: Forgot to add that I have tried to add eventhandlers with all the possible combinations of useCapture, but they all had the same result.

Comment: Please show the relevant code so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Just tried that with a div element and I couldn't fire the mousemove event with only pressing a button. Using Firefox 45

Comment: Damn it's quite a big chunk of code. Give me a moment to shrink it down for you!

Comment: A demo on JSFiddle will do, too.

Comment: Post edited with jsfiddle

Comment: Actually, i should have tested before, but I tried on Microsoft Edge and it doesn't fire, while on Chrome or Chromium it does fire! Chromium bug?!

Comment: [A dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538743/what-to-do-if-mousemove-and-click-events-fire-simultaneously)?

Comment: Right, should be.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve was having the same issue. Solve comparing the previus mouse position with new mouse position :

```
function onMouseDown (e) {
    mouseDown = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
    console.log("click");
}

function onMouseMove (e) {
    //To check that did mouse really move or not
    if ( e.clientX !== mouseDown.x || e.clientY !== mouseDown.y) {
        console.log("move");
    }
}
```

Taken from here : [What to do if "mousemove" and "click" events fire simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538743/what-to-do-if-mousemove-and-click-events-fire-simultaneously)